# Tableau: Sum based on Rank

Tags: tableau-api, rank, level-of-detail

With *customers* on the row level I have two columns: *Revenue* and *Rank*.

*Revenue* is the sum of that customers spend YTD.

*Rank* is a Calculated Field composed of `Rank([Revenue])` then modified to Down Pane.

I'm looking, via another calculated field, to sum the revenue totals of only those customers in the top five. I tried using the following:

```
SUM(IF [Rank] <6 THEN [Revenue]
ELSE 0
END)
```

However, this returns the sum of all customers regardless of rank. I've looked into Level of Detail expressions but it seems like I can't use them with table calculations.

Screen grab below - any help would be much appreciated.

t

[Tableau Screen Grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7k5v.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please see the link below. Shows one method on how to customize the grand total and is a good site in general for tableau tips.

http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/customizing-grand-totals-part-1/